# jquery.slideViewerPro.1.5

Tags: jquery

Hi I have this script in test.php

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('.tabburk').click(function () {  
    $("#pozadie").load("galtest.php");
  });
});
```

And this in galtest.php

```
$(window).bind("click", function() {
  $("div#basic").slideViewerPro();
});
```

But when I click a div, or button or link, slideviewer only starts to load, but did not finish. Without `$('.tabburk').click(function () {` slideviewer loads properly. What I can do to load it properly after using `$('.tabburk').click(function () {`?

Hope someone can understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I have to use `$(document).bind("ready", function() {` instead of `$(window).bind("click", function() {` Now it works as I need.